# React-Native + ApolloJS: Sequential Requests without await

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Package info:

```
  "@apollo/client": "^3.6.8",
  "apollo-link-logger": "^2.0.0",
  "apollo-link-token-refresh": "^0.4.0",
  "graphql": "^16.5.0",
  "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-native": "=0.68.0",
```

I am making sequential requests in React.FC by calling Apollo client repeatedly, awaiting each request.

```
 const loadData = async() => {
    await wait(800);
    await dataService1.getData1();
    await dataService1.getData2();
    await dataService1.getData3();
    await dataService1.getData4();
    await dataService1.getData5();
    await dataService2.getData6();
    await dataService3.getData7()
    setLoading(false);
};
```

It works ... but slowly. It takes about 11+ seconds to load.
I’ve tried to remove await in the function above, but after that Apollo doesn’t send all requests, some requests are simply not sent.

Each request calls intercepter in middleware chain (for adding auth Bearer token) so the root cause of that issue can be in httplink which is at the end of middleware pipe.

```
  // Constructor of ApolloClientService
  this.httpLink = createHttpLink({
            uri: `https://${this.api}/graphql`,
        });

        // this.httpLink = new BatchHttpLink({ uri: `https://${this.api}/graphql`});

  this.link = split(({ query }) => {
            const {
                kind,
                operation,
            }: {
                kind: string;
                operation?: string;
            } = getMainDefinition(query);
            return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
  }, this.httpLink);

  this.defaultOptions = {
            watchQuery: {
                fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
                errorPolicy: 'ignore',
            },
            query: {
                fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
                errorPolicy: 'all',
            },
            mutate: {
                // errorPolicy: 'all',
            },
        };

  this.client = new ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>({
            link: ApolloLink.from([
                onError(this.handleError),
                setContext(this.interceptRequest),
                apolloLogger,
                this.httpLink,
            ]),
            cache: new InMemoryCache(),
            defaultOptions: this.defaultOptions,
            connectToDevTools: false,
            queryDeduplication: false,
   });
```

I haven’t found any workable solution yet without using
BatchLink (our server does not support batches, and we don’t have time now for refactoring,
Apollo hooks (useQuery/useMutation) or Apollo react component.

I think that ApolloJS must wait for the last request to complete before it’s ready to send a new one. I hope it’s not the case.

I’m looking for a solution to be able to send a chain of the requests (not a number of GraphQL queries) concurrently/in parallel like in the REST API from Apollo client.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)? That is: `await Promise.all[dataService1.getData1(), dataService1.getData2(), dataService1.getData3(), dataService1.getData4(), dataService1.getData5(), dataService2.getData6(), dataService3.getData7()]);`

Comment: @Kapobajza, Promise.all have same result that just without 'await'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem on server-side. Gateway return 504 timeout

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `getData1-7` each represent a GraphQL query you can run them all in a single request:

```
query doItAll($par1: String, $par2: Number) {
   getData1(par1: $par1) {
     … getData1 fields
   }
   getData2(par2: $par2) {
     … getData2 fields
   }
…
}
```

Comment: We can't merge queries to single request because it need too much changes for this way. I wanna find a simple solution. For expample RelayJS support concurrent requests and we can set max of requests count via relay-compiler config properties. Thx for answer!